# Splitting character vector in my data frame by "|" not working

Tags: r, strsplit

Working on Tidy Tuesday's data set `horror_movies.csv` and I cannot see how to split the genres column. I tried:

`fieldList <- strsplit(df$genres, $"|")`

Here is a sample of the output:

`[1] "D" "r" "a" "m" "a" "|" " " "H" "o" "r" "r" "o" "r" "|" " " "S" "c" "i" "-" "F" "i"
[22] "|" " " "T" "h" "r" "i" "l" "l" "e" "r"`

For some reason this splits my elements into individual characters. Here is a glimpse of this column so you can see how it is structured in the data frame:

`$ genres  <chr> "Drama| Horror| Thriller", "Horror", "Horror", "Comedy| Horror…`

Is the `|` character special in R? What am I missing?

Comment: Use `fixed = TRUE` i.e. `strsplit(df$genres, "|", fixed = TRUE)` as `|` is a metacharacter meaning `OR`

Comment: Thank you! I corrected code to fieldList <- strsplit(df$genres, split = "| ", fixed = TRUE) and it worked as intended. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In R '|' is a logical operator meaning 'OR'.

You can do the following to solve the error, turn `fixed=TRUE`, this is set to `FALSE` by default.

```
fieldList <- strsplit(df$genres, $"|", fixed=TRUE)
```

Below is the documentation of the above function `strsplit`:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/strsplit

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer, if it resolved the problem